# Image naming for Baidu SEO

Tags: seo, baidu

Will it be helpful if we put chinese filenames instead? Like 运动健身.png

Or will it be better if we use alphabets that tells chinese characters instead? Like yundongjianshen.png

Or will will English filename be better? Like motion-fitness.png